# How to print only first winner in v-for loop?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to print only one winner inside a `v-for` loop. But I can't figure out how to do it?

```
<div id="app">
   <div v-for="user in users">
       <div v-if="user.is_winner == 'winner'">
         <p>{{user.name}}</p>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

app:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        users: [{
            "name": "Mike",
            "is_winner": "winner"
        }, {
            "name": "Piter",
            "is_winner": "fail"
        }, {
            "name": "Jow",
            "is_winner": "fail"
        }, {
            "name": "John",
            "is_winner": "winner"
        }]
    }
})
```

I need to print only one winner. Name does not matter.

https://jsfiddle.net/w3f4u2ag/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data inside the `users` array is not properly formatted. You can use the following to only print the first winner:

```
<div id="app">
  <p> {{users.find(u => u.is_winner == 'winner').name}}</p>
</div>
```

essentially avoiding a `v-for` loop altogether. However depending on your app's goal and the true meaning of the `users` array, you might want to consider filtering the data before they reach your view (HTML)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    users: [    
    {
      "name": "Mike",
      "is_winner": "winner"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Piter",
      "is_winner": "fail"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Jow",
      "is_winner": "fail"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "John",
      "is_winner": "winner"
        }]
  },
  computed: {
    firstWinner () {
      return this.users.find(user => user.is_winner === "winner")
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
   <p>{{firstWinner.name}}</p>
</div>
```

This is what seems to correspond best to your use case if you are in a Vue application. A computed property will be processed only if the data it is related to is changed.

you could also avoid an error if there is no winner, updating your HTML with:

```
   <p v-if="firstWinner !== undefined">{{firstWinner.name}}</p>
```

[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ulysse_bn/946gn31L/4/).